# Can't give a correct path to a function in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I'm trying to convert PDF files to Excel files using C#. 
When I write this :

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    var f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus { Serial = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

    f.OpenPdf(file.OpenRead());

    if (f.PageCount > 0)
        f.ToExcel(@"d:\File.xls");
}
```

It works, but When I write this :

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    var f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus { Serial = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

    f.OpenPdf(file.OpenRead());

    if (f.PageCount > 0)
        f.ToExcel(@"d:" + file.FullName + "xls");
}
```

It doesn't work. How can I change this line to make it work?

```
f.ToExcel(@"d:" + file.FullName + ".xls");
```

Comment: You are missing the `'\'` and `'.'` after `d:` you path should be `f.ToExcel(@"d:\" + file.FullName + ".xls");`

Comment: This is where a debugger is very helpful. Plop a breakpoint on the `file.FullName` line and see what the value actually is,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.Fullname` already contains the full path. Thus omit "d:" at the beginning.

Comment: I tried `f.ToExcel(@" + file.FullName);` and `f.ToExcel(file.FullName);` but none of them produced xls files.

Comment: in your code `file` is a .PDF file, but you hardcoded an ".XLS" file...?

Answer (score 1):

[`FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the full name **including the extension**. So in the first instance you're trying to write an Excel file with the wrong extension. While this would work on Unix systems, Windows likes the extension to be correct. By hardcoding ".xls" you changed your filename to:

> @"d:\Path\File.pdf.xls"

which is correct, but confusing.

You will need to strip the ".pdf" off the file and replace it with ".xls". The simplest way to do this is probably:

```
string filename = file.FullName.Replace(".pdf", ".xls");
f.ToExcel(filename);
```

As `Fullname` already contains the leading drive letter.

This will change *all* occurrences of ".pdf" to ".xls" so if that string appears elsewhere in the path it will get changed there as well.